# Java System.getProperty("user.home") how return home for other user (pi)?

Tags: java, linux, raspbian, home-directory

I am executing a java program as a .jar file on RPI, in which it is critical to receive the right home path of the user "pi".

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

returns me /root, what is the wrong directory and messes up my file structure since in that dir. I am creating further folders etc.
I am starting the program as user pi.

How can I receive the right homefolder for a certain user (in my case pi, "/home/pi/") without hacking?

PS: That user could be entered as an argument ofcourse.

```
Raspbian stretch
openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+1-Raspbian-1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.3+1-Raspbian-1, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no clean (portable) way to find information about another user in Java.

If you are OK with an operating system specific solution (for a Linux-based system), you can use `Process` and friends to run the `getent passwd` external command, then read and parse its output.

The `getent passwd` output consists of one line per matched user.  Each line consists of a number of colon separated fields, so you could parse the lines using `String::split`.  On my system, the user's home directory is the 6th field in the entry.

For more information, read `man getent` and the javadocs for `Process` and `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Hm not very sufficent, a pity. Then I'd rather go with try{ for the /home/$user path.

Comment: That won't work.  The user's home directory is not necessarily in "/home".   Trust me you can't use a heuristic.  You need to consult the sources of information that `getent` is looking at ... and it could be different places; e.g. /etc/passwd, LDAP, etc.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.