# How to access "user.home" with Java on a Raspberry Pi and write to it?

Tags: java, file, raspberry-pi, filesystems, system-properties

I have some issues creating files on a Raspberry Pi. The same code runs on Windows without any problems...

Surprisingly `System.getProperty("user.home");` returns just `/`.

`System.getProperty("user.dir");` returns `/var/lib/abc` but i guess my application has no access to it.

The code:

```
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/def";
    File file =  new File("/a.txt");
    file.delete();
    try {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(value);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exceptions:

```
/var/lib/abc/def/a.txt (No such file or directory)     
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:157) 
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:112) 
java.base/java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:60)
```

- 

```
No such file or directory
java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1035)
```

- 

```
/var/lib/abc/def/a.txt (No such file or directory) 
java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:237)
java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:187)
java.base/java.io.FileWriter.(FileWriter.java:96)
```

Any ideas where and how to create a file without access restrictions? It should work across plattforms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java System.getProperty("user.home") how return home for other user (pi)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125017/java-system-getpropertyuser-home-how-return-home-for-other-user-pi)

Comment: @MarsAtomic No, I've already seen this post. I am not trying to find out any user information. I'm just trying to save a file "somewhere". But it has to work across platforms (Windows and Linux) and Raspberry Pi os isn't working right now...

Comment: My feeling is this is a speciality to how the user is created. Did you check where the user's home directory is and what privileges apply outside Java? Then at least you know the problem is OS related and not Java.

Answer (score -1):

Try Runtime.getRuntime().exec(),

```
public static String getUserHomeDir() throws IOException {
      return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "echo $HOME"}).getInputStream())).readLine();
}
```

use `pwd` for user.dir

Comment: This would help if the system property would contain a wrong value. I doubt that this workaround will deliver a different value, and I doubt it will resolve the access privileges.